# How to pass variable from Form to Workbook VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to keep a variable from Form to Workbook Events, it works from Form to Module, but doesn't work from Form to Workbook Event, the Variable "Salvar" stay as "Empty" rather than "True"...

'WorkBook Event

> ```
> Public Salvar As Boolean
> Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
>
> UserForm_Salvar.Show 'Calls "Private Sub Botao_Salvar_Click()"
>
> If SaveAsUI = True Then
>     If Salvar = True Then
>         Cancel = False
>         Salvar = False
>     Else
>         Cancel = True
>     End If
> End If
>
> End Sub
> ```

'UserForm

> ```
> Private Sub Botao_Salvar_Click() 
>
> Dim PassWord As Variant
>
> PassWord = Senha_TextBox
>
> If PassWord = 123 Then
>     Unload UserForm_Salvar
>     Salvar = True
> End If
>
> End Sub 'Go back to "Workbook_BeforeSave"
> ```

Comment: The default for a Boolean is False not Empty. What is the value of SaveAsUI?  Have you tried setting a breakpoint at If SaveAsUI = True Then so you can single step through the code and check the value of the variables at each step in the immediate window?

Comment: Don't `Unload NameOfTheForm`, that unloads the default instance, which isn't necessarily the instance being shown. Rule of thumb you never need to unload a form, even less in that form's own code-behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need a global variable if you declare the form as an object, which is the better practice anyway, and then handle it correctly. Use any of the form's properties or the form's controls' properties to convey the message. I recommend to use the `Tag` property. Here is the code in the worksheet's module. Observe that I named the form `FrmSalvar`.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    ' 091
    
    Dim Form        As FrmSalvar
    
    If SaveAsUI = True Then
        Set Form = New FrmSalvar            ' create a new instance of the form
        With Form
            .Show                           ' the Form takes control

            ' code resumes here with Form hidden but still in memory
            Cancel = (Val(.Tag) <> True)    ' True = -1
        End With
        Unload Form                         ' only now the form is destroyed
        Set Form = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

and the code in the Form's code sheet.

```
Private Sub Botao_Salver_Click()
    ' 091

    Dim PassWord As String              ' Textboxes handle text = strings

    PassWord = Senha_TextBox.Value      ' this is a string, even if numeric
    If PassWord = "123" Then
        Me.Tag = -1                     ' write something to the Tag property
    Else
        MsgBox "The password is incorrect", vbInformation, "Access denied"
    End If
    Me.Hide                             ' hide the form
End Sub
```

The line `Cancel = (Val(.Tag) <> True)` in the BeforeSave procedure will crash if the user closed the form using the X button. This is because that button effectively unloads the form before your code can do it. In your system, that action should be paramount to "no password". Therefore this code will remedy the situation.

```
On Error Resume Next
Cancel = (Val(.Tag) <> True)
If Err.Number Then Cancel = True
```

That's a more dignified exit than gathering your skirts and fleeing the scene in panic. However, there is also a method by which you can simply not allow the form to be closed that way. I use the two event procedures below in most of my forms.

```
Private Sub CmdCancel_Click()
    ' 091
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    ' 091
    
    Cancel = (CloseMode <> vbFormCode)
    If Cancel Then CmdCancel_Click
End Sub
```

Read up about the QueryClose event [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/queryclose-event). In its above incarnation it just cancels what the user pressed and suggests alternative code which could be simply `Me.Hide`. I have `Me.Hide` in the procedure that responds to the Cancel button on my form and I rather invoke that procedure than allowing a second cancel exit from the form in my code. In this way there are just two exits from my form, with *OK* or with *Cancel*. Pressing the X is handled in the same way as when *Cancel* was pressed. Either way, the Me.Tag is preserved until the bitter end.

Comment: Works perfectly, but there's one problem when I close de Form on the "X", .Tag is setted as "<automation error". I fixed the problem using "on error goto xEnd >>> xEnd: Cancel = True". There is another solution for the "<automation error"?

Comment: I have expanded my answer to deal with your query.

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of Salvar before Unloading the UserForm.

```
If PassWord = 123 Then
    Salvar = True
    Unload UserForm_Salvar
End If
```